# How to configure silent alerts in xtify

Tags: javascript, xtify, applicationcraft

I am using Xtify with an ApplicationCraft app, the xtify call is done on the server

```
return  ssj.httpRequestAdv("http://api.xtify.com/2.0/push", "POST", JSON.stringify(objXtify), "JSON", {"Content-Type":"application/json"});
```

The problem is configuring the xtify object to suppress the visual and audible alerts.

```
xtify = {
    "apiKey": _apiKey,
    "appKey": _appKey,
    "xids": _populateXIDArray(obj),
     "content": {
        "subject": _populateSubject(obj),
        "message": _populateMessage(obj),
        "action": {
            "type": "NONE",
            "data": "CST",
            "label": _populateLabel(obj)
        },
        "sound": "default.caf", //default.caf
        "badge": "+1"
    }
};
```

Setting "type": "NONE" has no effect on the alert.

My aim is to trigger a response from the app (if currently running) without interrupting the user.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a relatively recent Xtify SDK, it includes "silence.caf". Set that as your sound and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to avoid the vibration in native push.